# Jquery post loading gif

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, loading

I have the following script

```
<script>
$('#event li').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $.post("A.php", { text: text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#result').html(return_data);
    });
    $.post("F.php", { text: text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#subresult').html(return_data);
        initialize();
    });
    event.preventDefault() ;
});
</script>
```

Now the scripts A.php and B.php take some time to load the results , I want to show a loading gif during that portion of time. The approach which I took was

```
<img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="loadingImage" style="display: none;" />
<script>
$('#event li').click(function() {
$("#loadingImage").show();  
var text = $(this).text();
.
.
.
```

However this didnt cause any change in the display. I still cant see the loader. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you check that the browser is finding the image? Also, did check if there's a css issue?  Try to take the display: none and see if there's nothing overlapping th image.

Answer (score 0):

first:
 1. Make sure that the actual image exists!
 2. The code seems right, so please click the #event li element and go to your site-inspector to see of any errors appeared?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `li` hasn't been created yet and your `click` event is not binding. So, use `$(document).ready(function() { ...// your code });`

I would write your code as something like this (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#event li').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $('#loadingImage').show();
        var loaded = 0;
        $.post("A.php", { text: text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#result').html(return_data);
            loaded++;
            if(loaded == 2) $('#loadingImage').hide();
        });
        $.post("F.php", { text: text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#subresult').html(return_data);
            loaded++;
            if(loaded == 2) $('#loadingImage').hide();
            initialize();
        });
        event.preventDefault() ;
    }
});
```